# Boot issues with opensuse 15 and vmware workstation 14

Tags: opensuse

i had installed the latest opensuse 15 using vmware workstation 14.1. i rebooted then ran update on the system and rebooted. the screen went black and did not respond. could not get it to comeback. it would boot until the gui was supposed to come up, but never did.
hi again, as i said i have vmware workstation 14.1 and was using opensuse 15. after it updated to latest it would not come back up after reboot. i could see that it was booting. then at the end when the gui is supposed to come up the screen went black andi could not get the os to react. tried alt f1 f2 f3. could hard reboot but same affect.

Answer (score 0):

For VMware-specific virtual hardware to work with a new kernel, initial ramdisk needs to be rebuilt to include the appropriate VMware-specific kernel modules.

Refer this solution - https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1002402